# Quote an cite with/without author with/without source HTML5

Tags: html

What is the best way to QUOTE and CITE (if available) ?

It seems there is no consensus about it.

Here's my work :
Exemple with **dead author with no real inline source available** (Yep, no internet when Nostradamus was alive ^^)

```
<figure>
 <blockquote>
  <p>lorem upsum </p>
  <footer>
   <em><cite>Nostradamus</cite></em>
    </footer>
 </blockquote>
 <figcaption>
    <p>HE's talking about Lorem and love</p>
 </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**General sentences** that people say and that **nobody know where it comes from**.

```
<figure>
    <blockquote cite="unknown">
        <p>Do the good, and then good will come to you </p>
        <footer>
            /*<em><cite></cite></em>*/
        </footer>
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption>
        <p>THIS talking about doing stuff</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Alive people (or something like that) that I can source

```
<figure>
    <blockquote cite="http://www.google.com/sourcepage.html">
        <p>Don't do evil. Just give me money with adsense !</p>
        <footer>
            <em><cite>Google</cite></em>
        </footer>
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption>
        <p>THIS is talking about business</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

the purpose is to don't do duplicate content (as google define it) and be able maybe to be display as "rich snippet" (this last point will need much more work)

any change/improvment ?

Comment: not clear, what you are looking here? Are you facing any issue or error?

Comment: It's irresponsible to drink and post.

Comment: I want to write the most desriptive code